# Cannot update or delete an inherited permission on a shared drive item

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer, google-drive-shared-drive

**Use case:** 
* Created a shared drive "Demo_Folder"
* For "User A" - gave Content manager access. For "User B" - gave Viewer access.
* Uploaded 3 files (file1.sv, file2.csv and file3.csv) to Demo_Folder
* For file3.csv, I would like to provide editor access to "User B". I was able to do this via UI. However, I am not able to do this using API.

**Here is the code:**

permission = {u'role':u'writer'}
service.permissions().update(fileId=file_id,supportsAllDrives=True,permissionId=permission_id, body=permission).execute()

**Error:**
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<***********>/permissions/<********>?alt=json&supportsAllDrives=true returned "Cannot update or delete an inherited permission on a shared drive item.">

Answer (score 1):

It's **not** possible to achieve this granular permission update for files inside a Shared Drives. You can only update the permission for the entire Shared Drive folder using its ID in the `fileId` field.

### File a Feature Request

Feel free to request this new feature here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106